# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate Label element using XPATH

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have a problem with test payment gateway pop-up handling with this HTML code:

```
<div class=""> 
<div class="legend">Select payment method</div> 
<div id="payment-options" class="grid clear count-3"> 
    <div class="payment-option item" tab="card"> </div>
    <div class="payment-option item" tab="netbanking">
        <label>
            <i></i>
            Netbanking
        </label>
    </div>   
</div>  
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I am using `XPath: //*[@id='payment-options']/div[2]/label`. I have to click image link but every time I'm getting an error as Unable to locate . Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Please share website and then edit it again once work done..

Comment: @Saurabh, There is no `div[2]` under `*[@id='payment-options']/` tag, in the HTML code you shared. There is only one `div` tag. Can you please let me know which element you want to click

Comment: @Karthik: My mistake, forgot to add the first div.

Answer (score 0):

from the html snippet you shared, i dont see the id='payment-options'
can you try using cssSelector instead?

```
By.cssSelector("div.option.item");
```

Comment: Now I have updated the HTML code. I hope this might help you to understand.

Comment: Try the following css selector then: "div[id='payment-options'] div[tab='netbanking'] label"